# На сервере timeweb не работает django-ckeditor в админ панели

Tags: python, django

на сервере:

Python == 3.10

Django == 4.2.9

django-ckeditor == 5.9.0 - 6.7.0

редактор установил согласно инструкции https://django-ckeditor.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#section-9 переписывать нет смысла

мои файлы:

**models.py**

```
from ckeditor.fields import RichTextField  
...                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
education = RichTextField(verbose_name='Образование')
...
```

**settings.py**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
...
    'ckeditor',
]

STATIC_ROOT = '/home/.../public_html/static/'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

получаю ошибку в консоли

```
VM1137 ckeditor.js:260 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'dir')

at Object.d (VM1137 ckeditor.js:260:54)
    
at w (VM1137 ckeditor.js:261:181)
    
at Array.y (VM1137 ckeditor.js:261:336)
    
at z (VM1137 ckeditor.js:261:420)
    
at A.CKEDITOR.env.ie.f.$.onerror (VM1137 ckeditor.js:262:429)
```

в консоли также появляются следующие пути: expert.umiic.ru/admin/experts/expert/4/change/static/ckeditor/ckeditor/config.js?t=N5UC expert.umiic.ru/admin/experts/expert/ 4/change/static/ckeditor/ckeditor/skins/moono-lisa/editor.css?t=N5UC expert.umiic.ru/admin/experts/expert/4/change/static/ckeditor/ckeditor/lang/ru.js ?t=N5UC

как можно решить это?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Может у кого случится тоже самое, мне помогло следующее:

- удалить папку с миграциями
- `python manage.py makemigrations`
- `python manage.py migrate`
- `killall -9 apache2`

Обновляем страницу, все работает.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте пересобрать обновлённую статику вашего проекта, используя команду в IDE (или консоли):
`python manage.py collectstatic`.

В браузере выполните хард-релоад с помощью `Ctrl+F5` (перезагрузка сбросит кэш страницы и обновит статичные файлы).

**Пример**

`settings.py`

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    "ckeditor",
    "ckeditor_uploader",
    ...
]

STATIC_URL = "static/"
STATIC_ROOT = Path(BASE_DIR, "static")

MEDIA_URL = "media/"
MEDIA_ROOT = Path(BASE_DIR, "media")

CKEDITOR_UPLOAD_PATH = "uploads/"

# configs
# ...
```

`urls.py`

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path("ckeditor/", include("ckeditor_uploader.urls")),
    ...
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

`models.py`

```
from ckeditor.fields import RichTextField
from ckeditor_uploader.fields import RichTextUploadingField

class SomeModel(models.Model):
    content = RichTextField(
        config_name="config_1",
        verbose_name=_("Content")
    )
```

`cmd`

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

Comment: делал, добавились файлы, создалась папка но в админке модуль так и не отображается

Comment: Попробуйте временно закомментировать CKEDITOR_BASEPATH и запустить проект без него. Отпишите, повлияло ли это как-нибудь

Comment: Это действие ни как не повлияло, все попрежнему

Comment: Посмотрел ваши изменения. Я, честно говоря, не знаю, чем ещё тут можно помочь. Сейчас отредактирую ответ и добавлю туда пример моего кода, может, будет полезно. У меня эдитор подгружается нормально (я, кстати, CKEDITOR_BASEPATH не использую - модуль сам находит необходимый путь, а если захардкодить неправильно, то как раз эдитор не отображается).

Comment: я правильно понимаю что если я использую только в админке мне в урлах его прописывать ненужно?

Comment: Посмотрите пример, что я добавил, и попробуйте сделать аналогично (обратите внимание на указание путей). Что касается урлов - мы прописываем туда путь для того, чтобы пользоваться RichTextUploadingField (это поле позволяет загружать изображения не только по адресу, но и с компьютера)

Comment: без изменений, ваш пример от моего отличается только тем что убрано условие и staticfiles

Comment: есть еще варианты, а то ТП хостинга говорит что это у меня в коде ошибка, а я в упор не вижу где и как исправить